# Using the sin link with 'logistic regression'

Tags: r, logistic-regression

Is it possible to use the sin link with logistic regression in `R`?  The logit link does not perform well on boundaries of 0 or 1.  The sin link allows parameter estimation on a boundary.  I know how to use the sin link in these situations with other software, but not in `R`.

To me this seems like a programming question, but if it is better suited elsewhere as a statistics question I can post it on `Cross-Validated` or it can be migrated there.

Thank you for any advice or suggestions.

Below are some examples in `R` code.  Only the first of the four models runs and provides good estimates and p-values:

```
N1 <-  20  # flips
C1 <-   1  # heads

N2 <-  20  # flips
C2 <-   0  # heads

model1b <- glm(cbind(C1, c(N1-C1)) ~ 1, family=binomial(link='logit'))  
model1b
summary(model1b)
predict(model1b, type="response", se.fit=TRUE)

model2b <- glm(cbind(C2, c(N2-C2)) ~ 1, family=binomial(link='logit'))  
model2b
summary(model2b)
predict(model2b, type="response", se.fit=TRUE)


model1c <- glm(cbind(C1, c(N1-C1)) ~ 1, family=binomial(link='sin'))  
model1c
summary(model1c)
predict(model1c, type="response", se.fit=TRUE)

model2c <- glm(cbind(C2, c(N2-C2)) ~ 1, family=binomial(link='sin'))  
model2c
summary(model2c)
predict(model2c, type="response", se.fit=TRUE)
```

**P.S.**

I think this is the equation for the sin link:

```
(sin(X * Beta) + 1) / 2
```

whereas for comparison the equation for the logit link is:

```
exp(X * Beta)/(1 + exp(X * Beta))
```

where:

```
X = design matrix
Beta = parameter estimates
```

So, if `make.link` allowed me to define the formula for my own link I could use the formula above.  But I kind of have the impression `make.link` does not operate like that.  Perhaps I am wrong.

**EDIT**

It seems like this method should work.  Although, it might require limiting the range of possible values searched to avoid multiple solutions.

First, regarding the link function: `(sin(lin.pred) + 1)/2`, note that `sin(lin.pred)` is bounded between `-1` and `+1` inclusive.  Therefore, `(sin(lin.pred) + 1)` is bounded between `0` and `2` inclusive.  Therefore, `(sin(lin.pred) + 1)/2` is bounded between `0` and `1` inclusive.  This inclusivity is probably what enables the link to return estimates even when probability is 0 or 1.

Here is an exhaustive search approach for estimating probability of heads when 10 heads are observed out of 50 flips.

```
observed.y <- 0.20

# First search between -10 and 10 for the single Beta in the model

lin.pred <- seq(-10, 10, 0.000001)

predicted.y <- (sin(lin.pred) + 1)/2

residual <- abs(predicted.y - observed.y)

my.outcome <- data.frame(lin.pred, observed.y, predicted.y, residual, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)

my.outcome[my.outcome$residual == min(my.outcome$residual),]

#
#          lin.pred observed.y predicted.y     residual
# 9356500 -0.643501        0.2         0.2 4.351732e-08
#

# Now search between -20 and 20 for the single Beta in the model 

lin.pred <- seq(-20, 20, 0.000001)

predicted.y <- (sin(lin.pred) + 1)/2

residual <- abs(predicted.y - observed.y)

my.outcome <- data.frame(lin.pred, observed.y, predicted.y, residual, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)

my.outcome[my.outcome$residual == min(my.outcome$residual),]

#
#         lin.pred observed.y predicted.y     residual
# 506944 -19.49306        0.2         0.2 1.213282e-08
#
```

Different answers are obtained as the search space is increased, but the point estimates are the 'same'.  I have not tried adding a covariate.  Maybe my suspicion of how the SIN link is used in the other software and my attempt to use it here are both completely wrong.  I can find nothing on the internet about the SIN link.

**EDIT - August 25, 2014**

I have been seeking statistical help with this question on Cross Validated:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/113043/sin-link-with-logistic-regression

as well as programming help on Stack Overflow.

The inverse of the SIN link, I believe, is: `lin.pred <- asin((2*y) - 1)` This returns the correct linear predictor as long as the linear predictor, `z`, falls in the range `-1 <= z <= 1`.  This inverse function might be acceptable under the conditions that there is only one non-zero element per row in the design matrix, i.e., dummy variables are allowed with no intercept to compare groups: e.g., probability of success for Groups A vs B.

The above proposed inverse link might solve the problem of the inverse and constraints on the search space in which case the next step is to incorporate this inverse link into a user-specified link function in glm in R (along with any additional required information to estimate proportions).

As such, the question may once again be focused on programming, rather than statistics.

**EDIT - August 26, 2014**

I have not yet been able to implement the SIN link into glm in R, but I did manage to write R code for the likelihood function with the logit link and solve with optim. Then I repeated that approach simply substituting in the SIN link. R code for both is posted here:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/113043/sin-link-with-logistic-regression

Both approaches give the correct point estimate to three decimal places. The logit link did a better job. I was expecting better performance from the SIN link than what I observed. Perhaps I made an error somewhere.

If I learn more about using the SIN link with glm I will post the code.

**EDIT - August 26, 2014**

Once I remembered to use `method = 'Brent'` (because I was only estimating one parameter) then both links returned estimates that matched the expected value.

Comment: Read `?family` and `?make.link`.

Comment: @BondedDust When I look at `?make.link` I get the impression it does not offer the sin link.  I get the impression I might somehow have to define my own link, and I have added the equation for the sin link to my post.

Comment: @BondedDust Although when I look at `?family` I do see a user-specified link, in this case the `logexp` link.  It is beginning to look like I will need to provide all of the same information for the sin link.

Comment: Yes;  you need to read and understand the directions and follow the examples. To get a user-defined link you need to define `linkfun`, `linkinv`, and anything else that `glm` needs to carry out the estimation process. I frankly did not understand what a `sin` would do (in part because it's going to be rather difficult to define an inverse.). You did not describe the modeling situation, so I figured you would need to thrash it out yourself.

Comment: @BondedDust Why would it be difficult to define an inverse for sin?

Comment: I was if you plot the "inverse function" you see it's not really a function. `plot(sin( seq(-6,6, by=0.1) ),seq(-6,6, by=0.1) )`. So I suppose difficult is not the right word but perhaps should be amended to "requires some care". There are special statistics in the 'circular" package.